Does connect syscall lead to undefined behavior when using nonblocking sockets?
I’m experiencing a very weird behavior in an SSH-like program I’m writing in C for Linux.
Code Overview
The code is completely nonblocking and designed as a reactor where all fds are registered to a list, and on each cycle I use select to poll all fds and handle read/write events.
The code being nonblocking means my sockets are set this way too using setsockopt, thus when the program tries to connect somewhere the syscall sometimes return the EINPROGRESS errno (which I expect since TCP three-way-handshake can take a while) and that is properly handled in the code.
Finally, when tcp handshake completes the fd is set as readable in select, I check the connect result and if it worked I mark the connection established.
Now the weird stuff
I tried my program on a different machine which runs an older version of Ubuntu and realized the program connected twice to the same IP address. Debugging my way through I proved that the connect syscall was only called once! (checked both with gdb, and strace).
I tried to setup a simple server  to see what is going on there and actually saw two connections incoming from 2 different source ports.
Both of them were accepted by the server and a quick moment later one was closed by the peer (as if the client sent a FIN packet).
When the client connected it always received EINPROGRESS on the connect call and some cycles later finished the connection successfully.
The same test on my dev machine did not reproduce the problem and worked normally.
Does connect lead to undefined behavior when using nonblocking sockets?
The only thing I can think of now is maybe Unix sockets are not supposed to be nonblocking when calling connect, but that doesn’t seem logical to me and also works on my local machine.
Any thoughts on what may cause this behavior to happen?
EDIT
This is a code snippet performing the same logic from my program.
P.S: I figured out I forgot to mention I compile statically against uclibc, so I joined a simple makefile showing how I compile using both glibc and uclibc. Bug happens on both builds.
Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define POSIX_ERROR_CODE (-1)
#define TIMEOUT_IN_MS (10)

enum args_e {
    ARG_PROGRAM_NAME = 0,
    ARG_IP,
    ARG_PORT,
    ARG_COUNT
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int exit_status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    struct addrinfo *address = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    int retcode = POSIX_ERROR_CODE;
    int sockfd = POSIX_ERROR_CODE;
    bool connect_in_progress = false;
    int connect_result = POSIX_ERROR_CODE;
    socklen_t option_size = sizeof(connect_result);
    struct pollfd poll_ctx;

    if (ARG_COUNT != argc) {
        (void)fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <ip> <port>\n", argv[ARG_PROGRAM_NAME]);
        goto l_exit;
    }

    (void)memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    retcode = getaddrinfo(argv[ARG_IP], argv[ARG_PORT], &hints, &address);
    if (0 != retcode) {
        perror("Getaddrinfo failed");
        goto l_exit;
    }

    if (NULL != address->ai_next) {
        (void)fprintf(stderr, "Warning: got more than one address from getaddrinfo.\n");
    }

    sockfd = socket(address->ai_family, address->ai_socktype, address->ai_protocol);
    if (POSIX_ERROR_CODE == sockfd) {
        perror("Failed to create a socket");
        goto l_exit;
    }

    retcode = fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (0 != retcode) {
        perror("Failed to set socket to nonblocking");
        goto l_exit;
    }

    retcode = connect(sockfd, address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen);
    if (POSIX_ERROR_CODE == retcode) {
        if (EINPROGRESS == errno) {
            (void)printf("Connect is EINPROGRESS...\n");
            connect_in_progress = true;
        } else {
            perror("Connect failed");
            goto l_exit;
        }
    }

    poll_ctx.fd = sockfd;
    poll_ctx.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;

    while (connect_in_progress) {
        retcode = poll(&poll_ctx, 1, TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
        if (POSIX_ERROR_CODE == retcode) {
            perror("Poll failed");
            goto l_exit;
        }

        if (0 == retcode) {
            (void)printf("Poll timed out.\n");
            continue;
        }

        retcode = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR,
                             &connect_result, &option_size);
        if (POSIX_ERROR_CODE == retcode) {
            perror("Getsockopt failed");
            goto l_exit;
        }

        (void)printf("Connect result: %s\n", strerror(connect_result));
        connect_in_progress = false;
    }

    exit_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

l_exit:
    if (POSIX_ERROR_CODE != sockfd) {
        (void)close(sockfd);
    }
    if (NULL != address) {
        freeaddrinfo(address);
    }
    return exit_status;
}

Makefile
CFLAGS=-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LDFLAGS=-static

all:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) main.c -o client_glibc
    # I installed a uclibc-1.0.39 toolchain from https://toolchains.bootlin.com
    x86_64-linux-gcc $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) main.c -o client_uclibc

clean:
    rm client_glibc client_uclibc


It's (likely) not a problem with your code. Could be a bug in the specific kernel used for the system. But it's hard to say without more details, like a proper [mre].

Does "FYN" mean FIN or SYN or a combination?

I meant FIN, edited it now, thank you.

AFAIK, connect with a non-blocking socket is supposed to be well-defined, and what you're attempting sounds valid, so this definitely sounds like a bug in the network stack.

Unix sockets are different from IP sockets btw

Please update this question with code that allows us to reproduce the problem locally.

Just did! Hope you manage to reproduce it now or find the issue somehow :)

First, try capturing your network traffic with something like wireshark to see what your actual network traffic is.  Second, try running your process under strace to see the actual system calls it makes.   And does the problem appear with both uclibc and glibc?  It's not clear from your question if it does.  Finally, the revents field of struct pollfd poll_ctx is uninitialized.  That shouldn't matter, but if something is buggy...

I used both wireshark and strace, connect syscall is issues only once, and wireshark + server logs show 2 connections being made (from 2 different source ports).
The problem appear both with uclibc and glibc, but does not reproduce on my dev machine, only on a different VM with older version of ubuntu (although compiling statically should make this not really matter to my understanding).
Thank you for pointing out revents, I fixed it now, bug still happens.
